# I try to multiply an Input put it just repeats the Input instead of multiplying

Tags: python

I'm **EXTREMELY** new to coding in general so i'm sorry if this is a dumb question but...
I'm having a problem, and that is when I try to add text to an Input multiplication (I don't know if it has a name) it freaks out.

I've seen a few "solutions" about it, and it works for specific cases, but it messes up in this one.

This is my code:

```
j = input("What is your age? : ")
j = str(j)
DogY = (j * 7)
print("Your age in dog years is " + DogY)
```

I'm trying to make a dumb "Your age in dog years is * blank *." thing but this happens, I can't get what i'm looking for. If I input something easy like 10 (easy for me because I don't have to do math), this happens

What I want is:

```
Your age in dog years is 70
```

Instead I get

```
Your age in dog years is 10101010101010
```

I'm sure it has the easiest solution but I can't figure it out or find the solution anywhere. Please help

Comment: `j = str(j)` should probably be `j = int(j)`.

Comment: Multiplying a `string` in python repeats the string even if the string contains a number.

Comment: Note that python _always_ takes input in the form of a string. You want an `int`, and so convert it to integer by `j = int(input("What ..."))`. Your print will become: `print('Your age...', dog_years)` since `int + str` is not allowed in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: It isn't a dumb question. Almost all beginning Python programmers get tripped up by how `input()` works at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest upside of python is its simplicity and flexibility in implementation.

In the below code,

**Type 1: Traditional way**

```
j = input("What is your age? : ")
j = int(j)
Dog_Years = str(j * 7)
print("Your age in dog years is " + Dog_Years)
```

**Type 2: Better way**

- We are setting up age with the constraint that it will always be int.
- Then we are multiplying without storing.

```
j = int(input("What is your age? : "))
print("Your age in dog years is " + str((j * 7)))
```

**Type 3: Pythonic Way**

- We are performing the operation without any usage of variables.

```
print("Your age in dog years is : ", str( int(input("What is your age? : ") )*7 ) )
```

Comment: Pythonic way will take getting used to. At the moment, it hurts the eyes. ;-)

Comment: Don't take it out on me, I didn't introduce short-hands. :P

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I probably couldn't have figure it out for a while, quit and started something else, now I'll study this and try to comprehend it in English :D

Comment: Not using variables is not pythonic.